# select from multiple tables, when one is never used

Tags: sql, multiple-tables

I improved my question with example tables for a better understanding

I have 3 tables with following rows:

```
TABLE1 t1                 TABLE t2              TABLE t3

ID   NAME    OBS          ID   HW_VER           ID   SERIAL
-----------------         -----------           ------------
1  | Name1 | Obs1         1  | HWVer1           5  | Serial5
2  | Name2 | Obs2         2  | HWVer2           6  | Serial6
3  | Name3 | Obs3         3  | HWVer3           7  | Serial7
4  | Name4 | Obs4
5  | Name5 | Obs5
6  | Name6 | Obs6
7  | Name7 | Obs7
```

Now, I want to select the id, name and obs when 2 conditions are fulfilled:

1. the id is present in t2 or t3 (never in both);
2. it refers to either t2 or t3 attributes (eg. t2.HW_VER='HWVER1'), never on both

I did something like this, but it's wrong:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id, t1.name, t1.obs
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3
WHERE t1.id IN (t2.id, t3.id) AND t3.serial='Serial6';
```

I cannot use unions, external tables or views for this.
Please let me know in case of further questions.

Thanks a lot for your answers, I really appreciate your time..

Comment: The question is, what are you trying to count?

Comment: Please post sample data with desired output -- your question is a little unclear.

Comment: Your problem is hard to visualise without understanding your schema. But your where clause is effectively an OR. try making it an AND: where t1.id=t2.id AND t1.id=t3.id.

Comment: A google search on "case construct in where clause" will get you started.  The details might depend on the db software you are using.  You didn't specify it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select from T2 OR T3 but never both?  I think you want something like this

```
select count(*)
from t1
where exists (
    select 'x'
    from t2 
    where MyPrimaryKey_Name = 'random_name'
    and t2.id = t1.id
)
or exists (
    select 'x'
    from t3 
    where MyPrimaryKey_Name = 'random_name'
    and t3.id = t1.id
)
```